# powershell query row limits for SharePoint online

Tags: powershell, csom, pnp-powershell, query

I am not a super scripter, but I have a requirement run a search query over a site with multiple libraries. The query is for all documents where a specific string (someone's name) appears.

I have 2 different scripts that I've tested and they work well, but I saw some stuff online about row limitations at 500 items.

Questions:

- Is this true, is there any clear documentation about this anywhere?
- If it is true, is there a way around it?
- When we say 500 row limitation, do we mean it can only *retrieve* 500 items, or it only looks *through* 500 items? Must be the former, right?

Thanks for your help. For reference:
Script 1 - slight variation from this: [CSOM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/108778/sharepoint-online-get-all-files-with-no-checked-in.html)

Script 2 - same as this script, but checking body not title [PnP](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/03/sharepoint-online-run-search-query-using-pnp-powershell.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please see below references for 500 search result limits.
For on-premise, there is a workaround to fix it.

**SharePoint Online** [MS Article Search Result Limit](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-limits)

*Number of rows in a result set:500
Boundary*

*To display the entire result set, issue more paging queries.
For Discovery queries the maximum number of rows in a result set is 10,000*

**SharePoint 2013-2019** [Search: query and result limits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits)

*Number of rows in a result set
500 rows*

*Supported
This is the tested and default value for the maximum number of rows in a result set, except for a Discovery query. For Discovery queries 10,000 rows is the default value. To display the entire result set, issue more paging queries.
You can change the value for the maximum number of rows in a result set by using PowerShell cmdlets to change the **Search service application property MaxRowLimit**. MaxRowLimit defines the maximum value of the query property RowLimit and the Discovery query property RowLimit. RowLimit defines the number of rows each page contains in a result set. You can increase MaxRowLimit up to 10,000 rows, this is the supported boundary.*